# Como usar ReadKeey no C#

Tags: c#, loop

```
int loop = 0;
while( loop >= 0 )
{
    int aa;
    int an;
    Console.WriteLine( " Qual o Ano Atual? : " );
    aa = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine() );
    Console.WriteLine( " Qual o Ano de Nascimento? : " );
    an = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine() );

    int id = aa - an;

    if( id >= 18 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( " De Maior, sua idade é:" + " " + id );
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( " De Menor, sua idade é:" + " " + id );
    }

    Console.Write( " Se não desejar continuar Press <n> para sair... " ); 
    Console.WriteLine();

    while ( Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N )
    {
        Console.ReadKey( true );
    }

} loop++;
```

Comment: Seria interessante deixar claro qual a dúvida e em qual parte do código é sua dificuldade.

Comment: Qual o seu problema?

Comment: certo obrigado, irei especificar melhor na próxima.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("Pressione <Enter> para sair... ");
while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }
```

Comment: Não responda apenas com código, explique detalhadamente o que o seu código faz e como soluciona o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode no lugar do `Console.ReadKey(True)` usar apenas um `break` para encerrar o loop é sair do código.

```
Console.Write( " Se não desejar continuar Press <n> para sair... " ); 
Console.WriteLine();

if ( Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N )
{
    break;
}
```